# How to control the amplitude of a Wien-bridge oscillator?

Tags: simulation, oscillation, wien-bridge

I am trying to design a Wien-bridge oscillator and understood the basic working principle of it. Now I got to the point where I want to add a system which would make the gain >3 during startup and <3 when exceeding the target amplitude range.

Apart from inaccessible textbooks, I could not find a proper explanation of the JFET variant. I understand the incandescent bulb one, but I feel it is not practical enough and it is difficult for me to simulate it. Can anyone provide a simple circuit with adjustable output amplitude (and possibly an explanation)?

EDIT:

This is a working schematics of what I found online:
[image]

from what I understand, the JFET stays open initially (really small resistance), then once the output voltage starts swinging below -0.7 V (or the treshold voltage of the diode), capacitor C3 starts being negatively charged due to the diode conducting. At that point the Jfet starts turning off (increasing its resistance), thus reducing the overall gain, until a stable point is reached.

What I don't get still is:

1. The function of R8
2. The function of R7
3. Is there any way to calculate the values of the components for a required amplitude? Or is it trial and error?

Comment: what's "the JFET variant"? Could you please add a schematic of that to your question? Otherwise, someone might end up explaining a different circuit than you have at hand.

Comment: Did you mean "gain control with JFET" with `JFET variant`? Better if you can put a schematic, though.

Comment: I included a schematic, which found from the links in the comment below. Reading through the material, it makes much more sense.

Comment: Adjusting the gain of this finicky circuit is too difficult, add another stage to adjust the gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for 'wein bridge oscillator schematic' (without the quotes) and go to images, you will get hundreds of schematics using light bulbs, bipolar transistors, JFETs, MOSFETs, photo-conductive cells, etc.  Many of these images are from pages with design tutorials.

Here is an example from this site:

[Great Voltage Stable Oscillator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251469/great-voltage-stable-oscillator)

Other examples:

https://www.industrial-electronics.com/electrnc-dvcs-9e_16.html

https://www.eleccircuit.com/wien-bridge-oscillator-circuit/

UPDATE for the additional questions.

You are correct about how and when C3 is charged.  However, you don't want the JFET to track the sine wave instant by instant.  You want the control loop to respond to the value of the wave amplitude averaged over many cycles.  R7 and C3 form a lowpass filter that does this averaging.  A DC voltage (with some sine-frequency ripple) accumulates on C3.  R7 limits the current into C3, setting how quickly the stabilization loop responds to changes in the output amplitude due to, for example, changes in the load.

If the output increases (again due to a change in the load), something has to discharge C3 and reduce its voltage, to increase the JFWTs channel resistance and decrease the output amplitude.  R7 cannot do that because it D1 is reverse-biased when the output is too large.  Enter R8.  It is the discharge path for C3.

How quickly the loop responds to an overvoltage and an undervoltage are called the attack and release times.  They are semi-independent.  R8 and R7 form a voltage divider, so they interact in setting the times.  For the values in the schematic, R8 is almost 10 times greater than R7.  This means that the loop will respond more quickly to an overvoltage, when most of the current through R7 is going into C3 (but a small amount is bypassing C3 through R8), than to an undervoltage, when C3 discharges solely through R8.

A characteristic of any R-C circuit is a phase shift or time delay.  The larger C3 is, the more smoothly and slowly the circuit will respond to amplitude changes.  With a small C3, a step change in the output load will cause the output signal to overshoot, then undershoot less, then overshoot even less, etc. until the output amplitude stabilizes.  In effect, the control loop is its own damped sinewave oscillator.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the function of R7 and R8?

- The resistor R7 determines the voltage which allows the diode to open and to charge the capacitor C3 (which provides the desired base voltage for the FET). It is, therefore, the resistor R7 which allows to finally adjust the oscillation amplitude .
- The resistor R8 is necessary to discharge the capacitor C3 a little (!) when it is not charged. This is because the gate voltage (determined by C3) must be able to increase and decrease.
- **Explanation**: When I say "charge" and "discharge" I mean that - during continuous oscillation - there is only a very small modification of the total charge (resp. of the voltage) of the capacitor. The charge (resp. voltage) swings around the bias point. But the period of this "swing" (which amplitude-modulates the oscillation signal) is dermined by the RC- time constant T=R8C3 and should be at least 10 times larger than the oscillation period.

Comment: Why is it necessary for the gate voltage to increase/decrease?
Also, don't FET devices have intrinsic gate capacitances. Would the circuit, therefore, theoretically work without C3?

Comment: We want do design a circuit and do not want to depend on parasitics (which are too small to combine it with suitable resistors.). The oscillation function is a process where no oscillator circuit remains fixed and constant at a condition that fulfills the oscillation criterion.  Instead, it is always a continuous control process where the the oscillation "swings" a bit around a mean amplitude. For a good design this amplitude modulation is rather small - but it does exist.

Comment: continued: This is equivalent to the closed-loop poles which are NOT located on the jw- axis of the s-plane (as desired in theory). The poles move slightly between the pos. and neg. half of the s-plane. Therefore, the voltage at the gate (the capacitor charge) must be able to charge/discharge around the desired operational point.